# Plots don't show under plots window in R

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

When i run any kind of plot in R, the plot shows up in a new window (Quartz 2 [*]). It will only show one plot at a time as well. This is really frustrating, as I want the plots under the plots window on the bottom right hand corner as usual. Does anyone have a solution?

Installed the latest version of R as well as update on my MAC.

Comment: Did you install the latest version of RStudio?

Answer (score 1):

i completely uninstalled R and installed it again. It works now.